# How to monitor a file in robotframework?

Tags: robotframework

I am using robotframework. When I debug a keyword I write I found that one file in the folder where the test script lies in is missing during the test runs. But the test scrpit is long.

My question is how I can monitor the file missing at runtime?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you could write a keyword that checks if file exists and put it into Test Setup. This way you can in what test file disappears.

Comment: @Pekka thank you for the answer. Finally I added a keyword in operatesystem to the suspicious points to find out who deleted the file. I will try your solution.